# Confusion - Assertion Appropriate Usage

Tags: java, assertions

I am taking this code snippet from K&B practice exams.

```
public class Later {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        boolean earlyExit = new Later().test1(args);  
        if (earlyExit) assert false;  // LINE 5  
        new Later().test2(args);  
    }  
    boolean test1(String[] a) {  
        if (a.length == 0) return false;  
        return true;  
    }  
    private void test2(String[] a) {  
        if (a.length == 2) assert false; // LINE 13  
    }  
}
```

The answer in K&B states that, LINE-5 AND LINE-13 are in-appropriate use of assertions.
I would like to know why. Here is my observation after reading topic of assertion from
K&B.

1.I do understand, LINE 5 is in-appropriate because it is using assertion to validate
command line arguments. Assertions should never be used to validate command line arguments.

2.In answer, it also states that, LINE 13 is also in-appropriate use of assertions. Good practice
in assertions states that, you can use assertions to validate arguments to your private methods. So
my question is why LINE 13 is in-appropriate use of assertions.

Any insights over this will be helpful.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for.  I think you should rewrite your question to be more clear.

Comment: I have re-iterated my question, please have a look and let me know if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertion (**assert** keyword in java) are used to verify the correctness of an invariant in code, precondition or postcondition. They are used to test your assumption in code to catch inconsistent state and are - usually - an indicator of a bug or a unwanted flow execution.
**Assertion are disabled as default** because they shouldn't throw in production **and asserted code is not executed**

```
public class AssertionTest {            
  private boolean productionCode(){
    System.out.println("Prodution code executed");
    return true;
  }

  private void assertion() {
    assert productionCode();
  }
}
```

with assertion enabled output is :

```
Prodution code executed
```

and with assertion disabled output is...**nothing**! ***so be carefully***

Syntax:

1. **`assert <boolean expression>;`** throws an AssertionError if  is false
2. **`assert <boolean expression> : <expression with value>`** throws AssertionError with detail message if  is false

In your example

```
private void test2(String[] a) {  
  if (a.length == 2) assert false; // LINE 13  
}
```

you are using it in a wrong way because the right way is

```
private void test2(String[] a) {  
  assert (a.length != 2);   
}
```

means: `a` MUST have a `lenght` not equals 2 else is an error

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) for Oracle documentation.

Comment: I'd rather say it means "if a has length == 2 then this is an error"

Comment: @bellabax this explanation makes more sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: your code is not correct, because it does just the opposite of the original code.

if (a.length == 2) assert false; // LINE 13  means  "if a has length == 2 then this is an error" , but you've written just the opposite in your "corrected" code. Either way what you've shown is the correct usage of "assert", although the original is still valid java :)

Comment: my mistake, edited to reflect original test as remarked by @SvetlinZarev

Answer (score 1):

Assertions are used to check for code invariants. You should never do input validation by using assertions, because usually they are disabled at runtime, that's why LINE 5 is inappropriate.

Q:Assertion advocates that we can use assertion to validate private methods.

A: Yes, you can validate private method's arguments with assertions, because they are not visible to the public - i.e. if assertion fails it means that there is a logic/programmers mistake somewhere in the caller, but I'd recommend using if/else/exceptions constructs. As I said above, you should never validate public methods, because in practice everyone can pass anything to the method and if assertions are disabled bad things will happen :)

Comment: what do you specifically mean code invariants? But test2 can be used internally also for validating, not necessarily for command line input validation.test2 could be used otherways also, so why Line 13 is inappropriate?

Comment: I mean some conditions that are always 'true'If they are not, than you hava made an error.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29

Comment: i don't understand why LINE 13 is inappropriate usage. I am sorry but line 13 still is not making sense to me.

Comment: well, you can use assertions to validate private methods' arguments, so I don't know why they say it's "inappropriate"
(I edited my post, because I didn't see that Line 13 is private)


http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137158/is-it-better-to-use-assert-or-illegalargumentexception-for-required-method-param

Comment: In the K&B book (p.264) the following rule for assertions and private methods is given:
"Do use assertions to validate arguments to a private method."
http://www.coderanch.com/t/249114/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Private-methods-assertions